# iptables-restore v1.4.12: iptables.xslt creates wrong output: Couldn't load match `ptcp'

Tags: c, xml, linux, xslt, iptables

I am trying to load data from xml to iptables. I am using the following command:

```
xsltproc /usr/share/iptables/iptables.xslt myiptable.xml | iptables-restore
```

But I get this error

> iptables-restore v1.4.12: Couldn't load match `ptcp':No such file or directory

I compared the outputs of `ip-tables-save` and `xsltproc /usr/share/iptables/iptables.xslt myiptable.xml` and I got this

output of `xsltproc /usr/share/iptables/iptables.xslt myiptable.xml`:

> -A INPUT -m ptcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

output of `ip-tables-save`:

> -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

Can someone please explain what's happening. Also, is there a standard `iptables.xslt` file that I could download?

Comment: Is there a better way to convert xml to ip-tables save format?

Comment: Thanks for the edit zx485

Comment: I extended my answer below and added a complete fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the output of your XSLT seems to be syntactically incorrect.

So `-m ptcp -m tcp` should probably be `-p tcp -m tcp`. IIRC `-m` is match and `-p` is protocol.

**I investigated this further**

It seems that this is a bug in `/usr/share/iptables/iptables.xslt`. The actual XSLT is out of sync with the XML format and therefore the output is unusable.

In the original `iptables.xslt`(2011-07-22) the output for match-extensions is checked with

```
<xsl:if test="name() != 'match'">
```

but there are no `<match>` elements in the generated XML file and so this evaluates to always true - creating the `-m ptcp` output (next to many other wrong strings).

**Solution:**

I rewrote the `iptables.xslt` replacing the first template matching the `conditions` with

```
<!-- output conditions of a rule but not an action -->
<xsl:template match="iptables-rules/table/chain/rule/conditions/*">
  <!-- <match> is the psuedo module when a match module doesn't need to be loaded and when -m does not need to be inserted -->
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="document('ipt-ext.xml')//@name = name()">
      <xsl:text> -m </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="name()"/>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(' -',name(),' ')"/>
    </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>     
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
</xsl:template>
```

This template needs a secondary XML helper file in the same directory for identifying the *match-extensions*, which are listed in this file I named `ipt-ext.xml`. Create a new file with this name and the following content in `/usr/share/iptables/`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<IPTablesMatchExtensions>
    <IPText name="addrtype" />
    <IPText name="ah" />
    <IPText name="ah" />
    <IPText name="bpf" />
    <IPText name="cluster" />
    <IPText name="comment" />
    <IPText name="connbytes" />
    <IPText name="connlimit" />
    <IPText name="connmark" />
    <IPText name="conntrack" />
    <IPText name="cpu" />
    <IPText name="dccp" />
    <IPText name="devgroup" />
    <IPText name="dscp" />
    <IPText name="dst" />
    <IPText name="ecn" />
    <IPText name="esp" />
    <IPText name="eui64" />
    <IPText name="frag" />
    <IPText name="hashlimit" />
    <IPText name="hbh" />
    <IPText name="helper" />
    <IPText name="hl" />
    <IPText name="icmp" />
    <IPText name="icmp6" />
    <IPText name="iprange" />
    <IPText name="ipv6header" />
    <IPText name="ipvs" />
    <IPText name="length" />
    <IPText name="limit" />
    <IPText name="mac" />
    <IPText name="mark" />
    <IPText name="mh" />
    <IPText name="multiport" />
    <IPText name="nfacct" />
    <IPText name="osf" />
    <IPText name="owner" />
    <IPText name="physdev" />
    <IPText name="pkttype" />
    <IPText name="policy" />
    <IPText name="quota" />
    <IPText name="rateest" />
    <IPText name="realm" />
    <IPText name="recent" />
    <IPText name="rpfilter" />
    <IPText name="rt" />
    <IPText name="sctp" />
    <IPText name="set" />
    <IPText name="socket" />
    <IPText name="state" />
    <IPText name="statistic" />
    <IPText name="string" />
    <IPText name="tcp" />
    <IPText name="tcpmss" />
    <IPText name="time" />
    <IPText name="tos" />
    <IPText name="ttl" />
    <IPText name="u32" />
    <IPText name="udp" />
    <IPText name="unclean" />
</IPTablesMatchExtensions>
```

---

**Application:**

From IPTables-rules to XML file:

> sudo iptables-save | iptables-xml -c > myiptable.xml

From XML file back to IPTables-rules:

> xsltproc /usr/share/iptables/iptables.xslt myiptable.xml | sudo iptables-restore

---

**Test case:** I tested the new stylesheet with these `iptables` rules:

```
$ sudo iptables-save
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.12 on Thu May 19 12:00:00 2016
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [11:568]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1:248]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [35:2284]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [35:2284]
-A PREROUTING -s 192.168.69.9/32 -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j ACCEPT
-A PREROUTING -d 192.168.70.124/32 -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu May 19 12:00:00 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.12 on Thu May 19 12:00:00 2016
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [138:40810]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [135:24836]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 65002 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -s 10.0.0.0/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 65003 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -d 10.0.0.1/32 -m connbytes --connbytes 1:4 --connbytes-mode bytes --connbytes-dir both -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Thu May 19 12:00:00 2016
```

Then I converted this output to XML with the command from above

> sudo iptables-save | iptables-xml -c > myiptable.xml

The resulting XML file looks like this:

```
<iptables-rules version="1.0">
<!-- # Generated by iptables*-save v1.4.12 on Thu May 19 12:00:00 2016 -->
  <table name="nat" >
    <chain name="PREROUTING" policy="ACCEPT" packet-count="3" byte-count="96" >
      <rule >
       <conditions>
PREROUTING          <s >192.168.69.9/32</s>
          <i >eth1</i>
          <p >tcp</p>
        <tcp >
          <dport >80</dport>
          <tcp-flags >FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN</tcp-flags>
        </tcp>
       </conditions>
       <actions>
        <ACCEPT  />
       </actions>

      </rule>

      <rule >
       <conditions>
PREROUTING          <d >192.168.70.124/32</d>
          <i >eth1</i>
          <p >tcp</p>
        <tcp >
          <dport >80</dport>
          <tcp-flags >FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN</tcp-flags>
        </tcp>
       </conditions>
       <actions>
        <ACCEPT  />
       </actions>

      </rule>

    </chain>
    <chain name="INPUT" policy="ACCEPT" packet-count="0" byte-count="0" />
    <chain name="OUTPUT" policy="ACCEPT" packet-count="8" byte-count="541" />
    <chain name="POSTROUTING" policy="ACCEPT" packet-count="8" byte-count="541" />
  </table>
<!-- # Completed on Thu May 19 12:00:00 2016 -->
<!-- # Generated by iptables*-save v1.4.12 on Thu May 19 12:00:00 2016 -->
  <table name="filter" >
    <chain name="INPUT" policy="ACCEPT" packet-count="127" byte-count="27749" >
      <rule >
       <conditions>
INPUT          <p >tcp</p>
        <tcp >
          <dport >65002</dport>
        </tcp>
       </conditions>
       <actions>
        <ACCEPT  />
       </actions>

      </rule>

      <rule >
       <conditions>
INPUT          <s >10.0.0.0/32</s>
          <p >tcp</p>
        <tcp >
          <dport >65003</dport>
        </tcp>
       </conditions>
       <actions>
        <ACCEPT  />
       </actions>

      </rule>

      <rule >
       <conditions>
INPUT          <d >10.0.0.1/32</d>
        <connbytes >
          <connbytes >1:4</connbytes>
          <connbytes-mode >bytes</connbytes-mode>
          <connbytes-dir >both</connbytes-dir>
        </connbytes>
       </conditions>
       <actions>
        <ACCEPT  />
       </actions>

      </rule>

    </chain>
    <chain name="FORWARD" policy="ACCEPT" packet-count="0" byte-count="0" />
    <chain name="OUTPUT" policy="ACCEPT" packet-count="78" byte-count="6909" />
  </table>
<!-- # Completed on Thu May 19 12:00:00 2016 -->
</iptables-rules>
```

And then back again from XML to `iptables`

> xsltproc /usr/share/iptables/iptables.xslt myiptable.xml | sudo iptables-restore

It all works seamlessly as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I got the output from xsltproc /usr/share/iptables/iptables.xslt myiptable.xml. Do you know any other method to convert xml to ip-tables save format? Thanks

Comment: It says
`#xsltproc /usr/share/iptables/iptables.xslt iptvho.xml | sudo iptables-restore
Bad argument `PREROUTING'
Error occurred at line: 8
Try `iptables-restore -h' or 'iptables-restore --help' for more information.`

Comment: What does the output of `xsltproc` look like(especially line 8)? My answer fixed _one_ serious bug in the outdated XSL, but it seems it did not fix the rest of them. You may edit your question with the relevant details like input strings and such.

Comment: It looks like this
`*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [7710145:475608142]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [197261:12769349]
:INPUT ACCEPT [190493:16814327]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [3314:207120]
-A PREROUTING
PREROUTING           -s 192.168.69.9/32 -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j ACCEPT
-A PREROUTING
PREROUTING           -d 173.246.70.124/32 -i eth1 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -j ACCEPT`

Comment: seems like there is an extra prerouting

Comment: @Souradeep Basu: I added a test case to my answer consisting of your rules in the previous comment. (Un)fortunately I couldn't reproduce your error. The `PREROUTING` rules are processed exactly like the `INPUT` rules.

Comment: Okay. I will try editing the xslt myself and see if anything can be done. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: It works perfectly. I probably didn't copy it right, the first time. Thanks so much!!